# Managing workers with RabbitMQ

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I have implemented rabbitMQ in my current php application to handle asynchroneous jobs that are handled by workers. But my current problem is that how should i monitor and scale up or down the workers. Also, i want to add error handling in case all the workers die. I have thought of following two ways but don't know which one is the better:

1. At producer end, i would analyze the rabbitMQ queue size. If queue size (list of pending tasks) is more than a threshold, i would create one new worker everytime producer script executes but before that i would check the server load (using linux command **uptime**). If server load is less than a threshold then only new worker would be created. At consumer end (in worker.php), i would apply same method to scale up the workers and i would also check that if script is idle for a given time (i.e. there is no pending task in rabbit mq queue) then it would automatically die (to automate scaling down of workers).
2. Second method is to use background process or cron to monitor and scale/up down the workers. But i don't want to rely on cron (as i have very bad experiences with it) or background process because if background process crashes for some reason then there is no way to recover from it.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend bothering to scale them down to nothing when there's no work to be done. The worker that's left (if you want to scale back to 1) will simply wait for something else to consume and it's not an expensive operation.

In terms of determining whether to scale up, I'd recommend leveraging the *RabbitMQ Management HTTP API* (http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/3646dee55e02/priv/www-api/help.html). You can use the *queue* related aspects via a *GET* operation to get information about *queues*, including how many entries are currently waiting to be processed.

With that info, you can decide to scale if it either hits a certain threshold, or keeps increasing with every check for a certain amount of time, or something similar. This can be done from the *consumer* side.

In terms of error handling, I would recommend encapsulating the *RabbitMQ* connection aspect of your workers such that if a *RabbitMQ* exception occurs the connection is re-established from scratch and continues.

If it's a more serious type of exception that isn't *RabbitMQ*-related, you may need to catch it at such a level where the worker basically spawns a new worker before it dies. Then of course there are other types of exceptions (out of memory conditions, for example), where it really isn't feasible to try to continue and your program should just completely die.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to answer your question with any degree of accuracy since there are many aspects of the context which are not included.

1. How long do the tasks take to execute?
2. Why do you want to scale up/down? Why don't you have threads waiting for load in the first place?

That being said, coming from the world of Erland and functional programming (which is the language used to power RabbitMQ) I would like to suggest the concept of a SUPERVISOR thread. This thread would have the following responsibilities:

1. Spawn threads depending on the load/qty of requests
2. Discard threads depending on the load/qty of requests
3. Monitor the children threads and re-launch them as required reprocessing the same messages if necessary or discarding them

The Supervisor thread should be as easy as possible and should be built in such a way that it simply loops, sleeps and checks if all the threads that need to be alive actually are - it can then check the load and spawn up or kill off the workers as needed. Or in other words, spawn more and/or not-spawn depending on your needs.

You could easily use an exchange to send messages to both the supervisor and the worker queues where the supervisor would then be able to keep a record/count of the messages in the queue without having to write polling code to the server, it would simply listen to it's own queue. You can increase/dec the counter from the supervisor thread and manage everything from there.

Hope this helps.

See: http://docs.dotcloud.com/guides/daemons/

Regretfully I don't program in PHP and therefore cannot give you PHP-specific assistance, this is however the programming pattern that I recommend that you use. If PHP doesn't allow multi-threaded programming and/or threads then I would highly recommend that you use a language that does since you will not be able to scale and use the full power of the local machine unless you use multiple threads. As for the supervisor crashing, if you keep minimal work in the supervisor and delegate all responsibilities to children threads then the risk of a supervisor crash is minimal.

Perhaps this will help:
Philosophy:
http://soapatterns.org/design_patterns/service_agent
PHP-specific:
http://www.quora.com/PHP-programming-language-1/Is-there-an-actor-framework-for-php

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please explain how can i implement solution mentioned by you in second point regarding threads waiting for load in php. As i understand, php doesn't support multithreading directly. Also, as mentioned by me earlier, how can i handle the case of supervisor thread crashing out due to any reason?